# Having a child call it's parent's version of their grandparent's virtual function

Tags: c++

Say we have a situation like this:

```
class Grampa() {
...
public:
    thing favoriteThing;
    virtual void sayFavoriteThing();
};
class Daddy: public Grampa() {
...
public:
    sayFavoriteThing() {
         cout << favoriteThing << " is my favorite thing!" << endl;

    }

};

class Son() : public Daddy {
    //How can I set the Son's sayFavoriteThing() to simply call the Daddy's sayFavoriteThing() ?
};
```

I want to set the lowermost child's function to be equivalent to his direct parent, without just copying and pasting the code. It seems like he doesn't inherit it by default as the original class has got it set to virtual.

Comment: You just do nothing, in this case. It is already inherited as such.

Comment: For your future questions, please provide a [mcve] so we can easily reproduce your problem on our machines.  You have a bunch of extra parentheses and ellipses in this code that cause syntax errors, and you didn't define `thing` or import the definitions of `cout` and `endl`.

Answer (score 2):

If the code is not working for you, I think it's because you forgot to specify a return type for `Daddy:sayFavoriteThing`.  Change the first line of that function to:

```
void sayFavoriteThing() override {
```